# I have Dataframe in pandas with column Case Number, True value, Predicted, confidence. I need to split values accordingly with all combination shown

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-datareader

**I have dataframe given below
[image]**

and am expecting result to be
[image]

is there any way to do in pandas
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not a "Pandas" way, because you'll end up having mismatched row lengths unless you do some Python formatting. Which, won't be very pretty. Can you describe your use case more? Perhaps we can help better if we know why you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: I have set of result of true label and predicted value with its confidence pipe separated, i need split it with all combination w.r.t  true label and predicted value. Assume in case one even if "D" is also in True label and "D" not predicted then even it should be included